# Delete char from String

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like this: `0000323530`, I need to eliminate all the 0 on the left until it reaches number 3 (for example, it could be another number ALWAYS different from 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the beginning zeros with nothing using regex.

```js
var num = "0000323530"
console.log(num.replace(/^0+/, ""))
```

Comment: Why would you want to match nothing ? That is what `*` will do.

Comment: I mean... 0 or more... It doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: In this case, it doesn't but if you were to replace those zeros with something, it matters, try `"123".replace(/^0*/, "REPLACED")`

Comment: Sure, but in this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: There's no need to justify or defend your mistakes, just fix them.

Comment: I really don't want to get into the weeds too much here. But what makes this a mistake? I could just as easily come up with an example: `"123".replace(/^0*/, "---")` because I want all of my numbers prefixed with "---" not just the ones that start with 0. It's completely arbitrary, no?

Comment: I think the following improvement would be better in terms of functionality and flexibility. Don't know how does it work in terms of performance. 

`["0", "000", "323530", "0000323530"].map(function(x) { return x.replace(/^0+(?=0$|[^0])/, ''); })
`

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex for that, here is an example:

```js
function removeLeadingZeros(str){
    return str.replace(/^0+/, "")
}

console.log(removeLeadingZeros("0000323530"));
```

`^` stands for the start of the string

`0` stands for the character **0**

`+` stands for one or multiple of the previous char or group

which means that this regex will match all the zeros at the start of the string.